# Activity Log are missing for the project

Tags: security, google-compute-engine

Today i logged-in to google compute engine activity and found that all past activity are missing.

https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?project=xxxx

How is that possible?

PS:
Also there were multiple owners of the project
Is it that some owner can delete the activity logs.

Comment: Logs should not be missing from your project. It is my understanding that users cannot delete these logs as they are an important part of viewing project past activity.

In order to address your problem you can create a public issue PIT request using [1] where you have to add your project number. After the request is created you should post the request code number here as a comment. I will use this code as a reference to find a solution to your problem & will post the answer here for you and the community. 

------
[1]: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164
------

Comment: yeah it was there.. for some reason browser was not rendering it.

Comment: I'm glad that you can see the Compute Engine Activity logs now. Kind regards.

Comment: Could you please put your comment: "yeah it was there.. for some reason browser was not rendering it" as an answer and accept it?